# how to post arrays to php

Tags: php, arrays, post

solved, **see my FINAL ANSWER post for complete details on what worked for me**

*original question and edits below:

looking for a way to set multiple sql items by a posted array.

i'm pretty sure I'm using php5.

here is how i set a single one, but i don't know much about arrays in php

```
mysql_query
("
    UPDATE comics 
    SET xml = UpdateXML(xml,'comic/pageNumber', '<pageNumber>'.$pageNumber.'</pageNumber>')
    WHERE id = $id
") or die(Err(mysql_error()));
```

i would like to Post an idArray and a newPageNumberArray from flash

where comic with id of idArray[0] would set its pageNumber to newPageNumberArray[0]   and so on.

the arrays would be of equal length to each other.  but could be of any length, depending on the number of altered page numbers in the admin tool.

for now i could just make a separate php request per item, but i think it would be much cleaner to send them all out in one php request.

***edit**

Thanks to Patrick i feel closer... but i still don't have it quite right.

flash sends these arrays

idArr: 34,24

pageNumArr: 1,2

in php i have this function

```
function changePageNumbers($con, $idArr, $pageNumArr){

    selectDataBase($con);
    echo '&startForLoop=true';
    for($i=0;$i<count($idArr);$i++)
    {

        $thisPageNum = mysql_real_escape_string($pageNumArr[$i]);
        $thisId = mysql_real_escape_string($idArr[$i]);

        echo '&thisPageNum='.$thisPageNum;
        echo '&thisId='.$thisId;

        mysql_query
        ("
        UPDATE comics 
        SET xml = UpdateXML(xml,'comic/pageNumber', '<pageNumber>".$thisPageNum."</pageNumber>')
        WHERE `id` = ".$thisId."
        LIMIT 1;
        ") or die(Err(mysql_error()));

        echo '&querySent=true';
    }
    echo '&endForLoop=true';
}
```

it returns this

thisPageNum=2&endForLoop=true&thisId=2&startForLoop=true&querySent=true

which seems out of order (maybe that's normal?)

more importantly it only lists thisPageNum and thisId one time, when the array has 2.

and still more importantly it lists thisId = 2.  the id's that are sent are 34 and 24

***edit2**
it works when i run it in html and manually set the arrays in php

```
$idArr = array(34,24);
$pageNumArr = array(2, 1);
```

which means that passing my arrays through $_POST from flash, is failing in some way.  I'm certain they are well constructed arrays in flash.  perhaps on their way through $_POST they become Comma Separated Values.

running more tests.

Comment: make a page that has this in it to check all of the information about your php installation: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: oh yeah,  PHP Version 5.2.15, thanks

Comment: are you trying to redirect the browser after submission with the `echo`s on the latest edit?  have you tried a `print_r()` of the two arrays that are posted, to ensure you are getting two separate arrays that are equal in length and are not multidimensional arrays?

Comment: i am not trying to redirect the browser after submission.  those echo's are for testing purposes.  although the way i have it setup with flash, it requires name/value pairs.  i haven't set this php up to run just from the browser, i have been using flash to test it.  also when i read the data after running this i notice the change doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send them all in one request and create a loop in PHP to update them one by one. As far as I know there is no way to do it in one statement, or you will have to create complex case constructs. That might lead to some better database performance, but it's a hell of lot more work for someone with little SQL exprience, so I should do it in PHP.

Don't forget to start a transaction. :)

loop:

```
foreach($_POST['variableofyourchoice'] as $id)
{
  // Execute the query using $id
}
```

Comment: im fine with sending them one by one from php to sql. but i don't know how to handle an Array in $_POST form in php.

Comment: When you name the POSTvariable `varnameofyourchoice[]` (ending with the brackets), PHP will make that variable an array automatically. You can then loop through that array using a simple for loop, as I will post in a second in the answer.

Comment: Alternative solution: Pass the ids in a comma separated value and use the `explode` PHP function to split that string into an array. You can then use a foreach loop in the same way to walk that array.

Comment: if i foreach the id's like that, how do i line it up to the same index on the pageNumber array?

Comment: You can pass the other values in a similar array (either given solution) and use the `each` function to get next items from the other arrays. Or you can use a loop like `for ($i=0;$i<count($yourArray);$i++)`. When you read $anyArray[$i], the `$i` counter should give you the corresponding item in each of your arrays.

Comment: @GolezTrol sounds like what patrick said to do, still working on debugging my code on that.  seems like i will have to make on that tests the function in the browser, so i can use printr etc for some clearer debugging.

Comment: Yes. I think Patrick and I had a very similar approach in mind. How is that debugging going. You can use `print_r` to print arrays, but could also use `var_dump` to display a broader variaty of variables.

Comment: see my FINAL ANSWER post for complete details on what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

set the data in an array like:

```
$uploaded_data = array(
    0 => array(
        'xml' => '..blah...blah',
        'id' => 231
    ),
    1 => array(
        'xml' => 'bleh...bleh..',
        'id' => 232
    )
);
```

**EDIT**
updated array data from $_POST
this is the way the data would look from a normal form POST

```
$_POST = array(
    'xml'   => array(
        '..blah...blah',
        'bleh...bleh..'
    ),
    'id'    => array(
        231,
        232
    ),
'submit' => 'Submit'
);
```

and iterate through the array and do an insert per each interior array

```
foreach($uploaded_data as $data)
{
    $update_query = sprintf("UPDATE comics 
        SET xml = UpdateXML('%s','comic/pageNumber', '<pageNumber>'.$pageNumber.'</pageNumber>')
        WHERE id = '%s'
        LIMIT 1;",
        mysql_real_escape_string($data['xml']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($data['id'])
    );
    $update_result = mysql_query($update_query);
}
```

**EDIT 2**
updated looping through $_POST data

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['xml']);$i++)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($i, $_POST['id']))
    {
        // if there is not a value for the id's at this count, break
        $i = count($_POST['xml']);
        continue;
    }
    $update_query = sprintf("UPDATE comics 
    SET xml = UpdateXML('%s','comic/pageNumber', '<pageNumber>'.$pageNumber.'</pageNumber>')
    WHERE id = '%s'
    LIMIT 1;",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['xml'][$i]),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][$i])
    );
    $update_result = mysql_query($update_query);
}
```

**IMPORTANT**:
ALWAYS set a limit on `UPDATE` queries.  An error may occur and accidentally update the entire database rather than a single row.

**IMPORTANT 2**
Make sure you always sanitize your db inputs as well, (`mysql_real_escape_string()`)

Comment: i want the array to be $_POST data. an array from flash, of any length.

Comment: @SketchBookGames i've updated the answer with the way that the $_POST data would look

Comment: thanks this seems helpful.  i have edited my question to reflect the current situation.  it's still not working quite right.  i sorta used your post as a guide,  i don't know what %s does and i had to improvise on the positioning of quotes a bit.

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL ANSWER**

The only way i could get the Post to go through correctly is using CSV's and PHP explode(); as **GolezTrol** suggested

and **Patrick** demonstrated the process of stepping through arrays in PHP.

so this is a combination of the assistance provided:

My final code after some testing.

**To run a test w/o flash**

```
$_POST["idArr"] = "34,24";
$_POST["pageNumArr"] = "2,1";
```

**To turn CSV's (Comma Separated Values) into arrays**

```
$idArr = explode(",", $_POST["idArr"]);
$pageNumArr = explode(",", $_POST["pageNumArr"]);
```

**Stepping through arrays and sending sql querys**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($idArr);$i++)
{

    $thisPageNum = mysql_real_escape_string($pageNumArr[$i]);
    $thisId = mysql_real_escape_string($idArr[$i]);

    mysql_query
    ("
    UPDATE comics 
    SET xml = UpdateXML(xml,'comic/pageNumber', '<pageNumber>".$thisPageNum."</pageNumber>')
    WHERE `id` = ".$thisId."
    LIMIT 1;
    ") or die(Err(mysql_error()));
}
```

**"Correct Answer"... goes to GolezTrol**

since there can be only one, i figure GolezTrol answered the question as stated in the title, while Patrick helped address underlying issues i would have had immediately afterward.

thank you both for your assistance and patience.